# Refactored all logic into hooks but now stuck using a conditional

Tags: reactjs

I've refactored all the business logic by hiding it behind hooks.

Before:

```js
function App({productId}) {
  const [item, setItem] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    (async () => {
      const found = await useContext(Store).find(productId);
      setItem(found);
      setIsLoading(false);
    })();
  }, [item, productId]);
}
```

After:

```js
function App({productId}) {
  const [item, isLoading] = useProductId(productId);
}
```

But how suddenly someone brought up a problem when `productId` is `null`.
I know I can't do:

```js
function App({productId}) {
  if(!productId) {
    return (<Loading />);
  }
  const [item, isLoading] = useProductId(productId);
}
```

Is my only recourse to go back and change all the hooks to accept `null`? Because technically null isn't an error state nor is it a loading state.

Comment: why don't you check the `null` value before start fetching data?

Comment: useEfect has incorrect dependencies ([item, products])

Answer (score 0):

Use `productId` as the dependencies of `useEffect`, which means the `useEffect` will be called when the `productId` changes. Then check `productId`, if it's `null` or invalid value, just return to end function call.

```
function App({ productId }) {
  const [item, setItem] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!productId) return;
    setLoading(true);
    (async () => {
      const found = await useContext(Store).find(productId);
      setItem(found);
      setIsLoading(false);
    })();
  }, [productId]);
}
```